# How to exit from "Edit as Table" mode in PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

When editing a CSV file in PhpStorm, I enabled "Edit as Table" and can not find how to close this mode. I do not know how to close the "Data" tab.

Help me please!

Linux Mint, Phpstorm v.2018.1.6

Comment: Just switch to "Text" tab? Show what you see there (whole IDE window ideally). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/editing-csv-and-tsv-files.html

Comment: What is the problem having the tab at the bottom of the file? You can just switch to Text tab ...

Comment: I'm having this same problem in IntelliJ IDEA. It seems "Edit as Table" is completely broken. The idea is great, but there seems to be no way to exit, and sometimes it only shows the top row and nothing else, which makes this view worse than useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked all over but couldn't find a way to do this. In the end it was bugging me so much that I just dropped the Jetbrains/IntelliJ project files and recreated them. This is a very heavy hammer for this problem.

If you have a Git repository this is usually as simple as...

1. Close your project if it is open
2. `git clean -idx` and select the project files to remove (**carefully**, if you have stuff you don't want to clean out! ***this deletes things!***)
3. Reopen the project and let it regenerate the project files from scratch

Tada! No more table editor mode. You may lose debugging profiles or other project specific settings, and YYMV :)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue in WebStorm and reached this thread. After painful searching I found these buttons to toggle between views in the bottom left: [image: Three buttons to toggle between views]

Answer (score 2):

The "Edit as Table" creates a split pane. Assuming you dont have any other panes open, you can close them all by:

1. `ctrl+shift+a`
2. Search for `Unsplit all`
3. Ta-da

While still destructive (if you use multiple panes), it doesnt go full scorched earth policy like @jocull recommends.